how i can use ascii code for send to serial port
I am beginner to C#, could anyone help me?
I want to send code to my board
now I am using ModBus Poll application, with modeBus Poll i got this Ascii code :
3A 30 31 30 36 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 46 39 0D 0A
(include space)
I wrote this:
could anyone help me, i know code is wrong, so i need to know how to send ascii code in C#
byte[] _mass = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII").GetBytes("3A30313036303030303030303146380D0A\r\n");
serialPort1.Write(_mass, 0, _mass.Length);


Surely those are the bytes? so: byte[] _mass = [0x3A, 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x46, 0x39, 0x0D, 0x0A]; ? or alternatively: var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":010600000000F9\r\n"); - possibly also simply ":010600000000F9\r\n"u8 if your API supports ReadOnlySpan<byte> (required for the u8 usage)

@MarcGravell  Depending on the protocol, the requirement might actually be to send the binary data as hex digits in an ASCII string. Some ports won't accept binary data as the upper bits might be reserved.

OP, in your question you say "include space," but in your code example, the spaces are omitted. Could that be the problem?

Serial port is returning a string.  So use following :             string input = "3A 30 31 30 36 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 46 39 0D 0A";
byte[] bytes = input.Split(" ").Select(x => byte.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();

You need to convert hex string to byte array.
How can I convert a hex string to a byte array?
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex) 
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                 .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                 .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                 .ToArray();
}

If you need to remove those spaces on your input, just do this.
    string input = "3A 30 31 30 36 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 46 39 0D 0A";
    string hex = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());

